# Google adwords: "An error occurred. Please try again later." message

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to upload a new campaign but always get a message:
"An error occurred. Please try again later."

On all fields:
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Does anyone know this kind of error?**

Comment: Are u uploading files...?

Comment: try it in Microsoft edge. my problem solved when i opened it in edge

Answer (score 35):

I found this post while researching the same error. I found that the Campaign Management editor did not like my exclamation points in the "Ad text ideas" fields. On a whim I changed them to periods and could then save.

Once the campaign was created I tried to edit the now existing campaign and change the periods back to exclamation points again but got the same error. Changed them to periods again and it saved just fine.

I'm not sure if this is what you were experiencing. Hopefully this info helps someone.

**Edit**

It's amazing that almost a year later this bug/feature is still there with no documentation or explanation. As Goktay alludes in the comments, one and only one of the "Ad text ideas" may contain an exclamation point. Any more will trigger this error.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer.  I had the same issue and removing the "!" from my text resolved the issue.  Funny, their example text has a exclamation point in it.

Comment: Had this issue just now. Changed all of my exclamation points to periods and AdWords have accepted them. Then I've tried to change only one period to an exclamation point and it worked too. I think there is a limit to them. Funny how Google just shows a blatant error message instead of explaining this.

Comment: Can confirm that having more than one text idea containing `!` results in this error. Bizarre!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Removing any exclamation mark from the "Ad text ideas" fields did the job.

Comment: This is no useful answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably a dead thread at this point, but I may have a solution for you all if anyone comes upon this thread in the future:

Certain punctuation can be taken as escape or function characters in Google Ads. Using a `\` in front of the punctuation can help to alleviate this problem. So instead of `Buy Now!` You'd write `Buy Now\!`. I just happened upon this solution last night, so hopefully that helps!